# why use admin panel instead of phpmyadmin for CRUD?

Tags: frameworks, symfony1

in some frameworks (symfony) you can generate an admin panel for CRUD operations.

i wonder why i should use that one and not doing CRUD directly in phpmyadmin?

what are the benefits with an admin panel?

thanks

Comment: As an aside, I strongly suggest avoiding using PHPMyAdmin on production servers as it is poorly-written and a common attack vector for hackers. A client such as SQLYog Community Edition is a good replacement: http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most important : You can implement a **business logic** and **check** what data are entered by the user.

*E.g. : you don't want to allow the user to change the unique ids of the products. You don't want the user to change historized data, like older orders.*

It is also about graphical and readability access. When you show a restaurant, do you want to see the Owner's id (e.g. : "A253"), or his name/telephone ?